# What's the scheme name of background of the line numbers in Vim?

Tags: vim, scheme

The bar where the line numbers are is gray in the following scheme: [**louver.vim**](http://jstap.web.fc2.com/louver.html)
I would like to change its color but can't figure out the name.

```
" Normal
hi Normal       guifg=black         guibg=white         gui=none
hi Normal       ctermfg=black       ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi NonText      guifg=darkgray      guibg=white         gui=none
hi NonText      ctermfg=darkgray    ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi SpecialKey   guifg=darkgray      guibg=white         gui=none
hi SpecialKey   ctermfg=darkgray    ctermbg=white       cterm=none

hi Cursor       guifg=white         guibg=black         gui=none
hi Cursor       ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black       cterm=none
hi lCursor      guifg=white         guibg=black         gui=none
hi lCursor      ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black       cterm=none
hi CursorIM     guifg=white         guibg=black         gui=none
hi CursorIM     ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black       cterm=none

" Search
hi Search       guifg=black         guibg=lightred      gui=none
hi Search       ctermfg=black       ctermbg=lightred    cterm=none
hi IncSearch    guifg=black         guibg=lightred      gui=none
hi IncSearch    ctermfg=black       ctermbg=lightred    cterm=none

" Matches
hi MatchParen   guifg=black         guibg=darkgray      gui=none
hi MatchParen   ctermfg=black       ctermbg=darkgray    cterm=none

" status line
hi StatusLine   guifg=white         guibg=darkgray      gui=none
hi StatusLine   ctermfg=white       ctermbg=darkgray    cterm=none
hi StatusLineNC guifg=gray          guibg=darkgray      gui=none
hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=gray        ctermbg=darkgray    cterm=none

" Diff
hi DiffAdd      guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi DiffAdd      ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi DiffChange   guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi DiffChange   ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi DiffDelete   guifg=white         guibg=black         gui=none
hi DiffDelete   ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black       cterm=none
hi DiffText     guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi DiffText     ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none

" Folds
hi Folded       guifg=black         guibg=gray          gui=none
hi Folded       ctermfg=black       ctermbg=gray        cterm=none
hi FoldColumn   guifg=black         guibg=gray          gui=none
hi FoldColumn   ctermfg=black       ctermbg=gray        cterm=none

" Syntax
hi Number       guifg=#0000d0       guibg=white     gui=none
hi Number       ctermfg=blue        ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Char         guifg=#0000d0       guibg=white     gui=none
hi Char         ctermfg=blue        ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi String       guifg=#0000d0       guibg=white     gui=none
hi String       ctermfg=blue        ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Boolean      guifg=#0000d0       guibg=white     gui=none
hi Boolean      ctermfg=blue        ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Constant     guifg=darkred       guibg=white         gui=none
hi Constant     ctermfg=darkred     ctermbg=white       cterm=none

hi Statement    guifg=darkred       guibg=white         gui=none
hi Statement    ctermfg=darkred     ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Comment      guifg=#006000       guibg=white     gui=none
hi Comment      ctermfg=darkgreen   ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Identifier   guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi Identifier   ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Function     guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi Function     ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi PreProc      guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi PreProc      ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Type         guifg=darkblue      guibg=white         gui=none
hi Type         ctermfg=darkblue    ctermbg=white       cterm=none

"\n, \0, %d, %s, etc...
hi Special      guifg=darkred       guibg=white     gui=none
hi Special      ctermfg=darkred     ctermbg=white       cterm=none

" Tree
hi Directory    guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi Directory    ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none

" Message
hi ModeMsg      guifg=black         guibg=white         gui=none
hi ModeMsg      ctermfg=black       ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi MoreMsg      guifg=black         guibg=white         gui=none
hi MoreMsg      ctermfg=black       ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi WarningMsg   guifg=red           guibg=white         gui=none
hi WarningMsg   ctermfg=red         ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi ErrorMsg     guifg=white         guibg=red           gui=none
hi ErrorMsg     ctermfg=white       ctermbg=red         cterm=none
hi Question     guifg=black         guibg=white         gui=none
hi Question     ctermfg=black       ctermbg=white       cterm=none

hi VertSplit    guifg=black         guibg=black         gui=none
hi VertSplit    ctermfg=black       ctermbg=black       cterm=none
hi LineNr       guifg=black         guibg=lightgray     gui=none
hi LineNr       ctermfg=black       ctermbg=lightgray   cterm=none
hi Title        guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi Title        ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Visual       guifg=white         guibg=blue          gui=none
hi Visual       ctermfg=white       ctermbg=blue        cterm=none
hi VisualNOS    guifg=white         guibg=black         gui=none
hi VisualNOS    ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black       cterm=none
hi WildMenu     guifg=white         guibg=black         gui=none
hi WildMenu     ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black       cterm=none

"Define, def
hi Underlined   guifg=darkmagenta   guibg=white         gui=none
hi Underlined   ctermfg=darkmagenta ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Error        guifg=red           guibg=white         gui=none
hi Error        ctermfg=red         ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi Todo         guifg=black         guibg=white         gui=none
hi Todo         ctermfg=black       ctermbg=white       cterm=none
hi SignColumn   guifg=black         guibg=white         gui=none
hi SignColumn   ctermfg=black       ctermbg=white       cterm=none

if version >= 700
  "Pmenu
  hi Pmenu                          guibg=gray
  hi Pmenu                          ctermbg=gray
  hi PmenuSel   guifg=white         guibg=black
  hi PmenuSel   ctermfg=white       ctermbg=black
  hi PmenuSbar                      guibg=gray
  hi PmenuSbar                      ctermbg=gray

  "Tab
  hi TabLine        guifg=gray      guibg=#505050       gui=none
  hi TabLine        ctermfg=gray    ctermbg=darkgray    cterm=none
  hi TabLineFill    guifg=gray      guibg=gray          gui=none
  hi TabLineFill    ctermfg=gray    ctermbg=gray        cterm=none
  hi TabLineSel     guifg=white     guibg=black         gui=none
  hi TabLineSel     ctermfg=white   ctermbg=black       cterm=none
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
hi LineNr       guifg=black         guibg=lightgray     gui=none
hi LineNr       ctermfg=black       ctermbg=lightgray   cterm=none
```

`gui` == gvim.

`cterm` == terminal.

`fg` == foreground

`bg` == background

Comment: for info: if you set `set termguicolors` (to have true colors in terminal) `gui` lines are going to be used